# Cannot login as super user anymore

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, root

I have an issue with login as root with in ubuntu.

I've mistakely assigning my user to a group as primary group and it is not anymore in sudoers.
Consequently I cannot use "sudo" anymore.

I tried to login as "root" but it doesn't accept the password. Or maybe, it has never been assigned.

So... am I screwed ?
Should I format the system and start over again ?

Comment: Do you use Unix or Ubuntu? It's not the same thing.

Comment: I use Ubuntu Server, does Ubuntu handle users differently ?

Comment: Not directly, but possible solutions might differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you use Ubuntu, you can select the recovery entry in the Grub boot menu. This will boot the system into the single-user mode, which will give you full root access, and the possibility to add your user back to the sudo-group.

Comment: IMHO this won't work: You'll have to enter root's password, which usually isn't set.

Comment: You don't have to. You will get root access without a password in recovery mode.

Comment: lajuette, Ubuntu doesn't require a root password to boot single-user.  Some distros do--but they *have* root passwords.

Answer (score 0):

no.

1. Boot using a live CD (e.g. the Ubuntu
   installation cd).
2. mount your root filesystem (`mount /dev/yourRootDeviceHere /mnt/directoryYouMustCreateFirst`)
3. alter `/mnt/directoryYouMustCreateFirst/etc/groups` and add your user to sudoers again (or admin, or whatever group is allowed to sudo)
4. unmount your root fs
5. reboot
6. be lucky!