# How to add someone back to the “root” user group after accidentally removing them in Ubuntu and not having another “sudo” user?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, user-groups

I have an Ubuntu installation without `root` user enabled (standard). The main user that was part of group `root` (called `netuser`) was mistakenly removed from the group adding another group and forgetting the `-a` for append.

How can I get that user running again? As I don't have other users to `sudo` with.

Comment: Not knowing specifics, the only way I believe this could be fixed is by launching the system in single user mode and manually adding them to that group by editing `/etc/group`. Or shutting down the machine and somehow connecting the hard disk to another system and just manually ending `/etc/group`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot login as super user anymore](https://superuser.com/questions/191834/cannot-login-as-super-user-anymore)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the suggestion in this question (recovery mode):

[Cannot login as super user anymore](https://superuser.com/questions/191834/cannot-login-as-super-user-anymore?rq=1)